# Why commandbutton action does not call to function in view layer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, primefaces

I'm doing some examples about Spring Framework and Primefaces but my button does not call to simple printf function in my view layer. How can i call my function and print some string on console ?

> This is my xhtml part:

```
<h:form id="jobForm">

<p:commandButton id="Print" value="Submit" 
actionListener="#{jobView.myFunc}" />

</h:form>
```

> This is my JobView.java file:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.myjob.model.JobModel;
import com.myjob.utility.Utility;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Component(value = "jobView")
@Scope(value = "view")
public class JobView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6901036085773777713L;

    private List<JobModel> jobs;
    private HashMap<String, String> cbLevels;
    private HashMap<String, String> selectedLevels;
    private String selectedLevel;

    public void startDataTable() {

        jobs = Utility.getResponse("http://localhost:8080/jobs/all");

        cbLevels = new HashMap<String, String>();
        //Filling hashmap here.
        cbLevels.put("Working", "Working");
        cbLevels.put("Graduated", "Graduated");
        cbLevels.put("Student", "Student");

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        startDataTable();

    }

        //My print function which i want to call
    public String myFunc(){

        System.out.println("Hello !");

        return "";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was because of Spring Security dependency in pom.xml. I deleted and it solved.